# Transactional kafka producer - doubled consumer lag

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a *transactional* kafka producer based on spring boot! versions used are as follows

- spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.3.0.RELEASE
- spring-kafka - 2.5.0.RELEASE

Our kafka (cluster) version is 2.1.x!

As a producer we *enabled idempotence*, defined the *transactional id prefix* and the kafka
template call is executed in transaction. We also have a consumer with *isolation level* set to *read committed* only!

Now here is a behavior we are coming across and not sure how to infer this,

- Producer sends *n-events* (10)
- Consumer (**not running**) lag is shown as *double of n-events* (20 whereas producer sent only 10!)
- Consumer (**running**) consumes only *n-events* (10) - exactly as much as produced

Can imagine few reasons why but then want to check the experts opinion as well, tried to figure it out from the official sources but not lucky so far! hopefully this is not too generic. Is this expected when it comes to the lag ? that the lag is doubled that of original number of entries sent by the producer (may be because one entry for each of the event sent by the producer has transaction information) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you notice the offsets of the messages consumed it might be alternate. 0,2,4,6...
Thats because of a "commit marker" message logged after every transaction.
This message consumes a offset of the topic.
So 1,3,5... will be consumed by the marker.
Since the consumer lag observes the offset difference the between the last consumed and the current offset the lag is double.